# Angular directives

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm studying the Angular library and have a simple (perhaps trivial) question about directives that might help me to place the term in proper context when reading general documentation:

When docs / tutorials refer to directives, do they refer to:

- The HTML (el, attr or class);
- The compiled HTML;
- The Javascript function that executes;
- The general concept of both working together;

Sometimes the context in which the term is used seems a bit blurry, probably because I'm still in study phase.

Comment: _A directive is an extension of the HTML vocabulary that allows us to create  
new behaviors. The directive can be applied as an attribute, element, class, and even as a comment_

Comment: This is somewhat related and has been a great help for me.  :)  http://toddmotto.com/killing-it-with-angular-directives-structure-and-mvvm/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is a feature of AngularJs to declare a *directive*. By declaring a *directive* you create something that allows you to extend HTML in various manners. So when people talk about *directives* they mean the whole thing which is is a pretty complex concept when you look at all details.

Mostly people talk about a "*directive*" when talking about the JavaScript function defining a *directive*, because this is how new *directives* get defined.

Most generally they do not talk about the compiled HTML in the DOM.

Comment: Thanks... this is where the confusion for me comes from. The concept is quite ok, but in tutorials and discussions, I have the impression that people tend to use the term interchangeably for talking about the HTML element (extension), the function or the concept. Sometimes that makes it a bit confusing for now.

Comment: I would disagree on the last paragraph, the whole purpose of directives is getting extra functionality compiled into the dom using the angularjs framework.

Comment: @Frankey: The directive is the thing that creates the HTML and puts it into the DOM. The piece of HTML then residing in the DOM is not referred to as directive. The thing behind defined in JS compiling and watching and doing all the magic, that's what is the directive. If I understand correctly you disagree with this. Can your point in more detail?

Comment: directive to create domain-specific features from DOM elements and allowing you to assemble views using business-specific building blocks.And angular provide all the other things to attach js..

Answer (score 1):

The definition of a directive stated by the Angular team  is pretty clear.

Directives are markers on a DOM element (such as an attribute, element name, comment or CSS class) that tell AngularJS's HTML compiler ($compile) to attach a specified behavior to that DOM element or even transform the DOM element and its children.

The context in which I use the term directive would be as follows:

I'm going to build a directive to lazy load images.

I have got an image:

```
 <img src="image.jpg"/>
```

Lets add a marker on the image element so the AngularJs framework knows we want  to manipulate that html element, or the html within the element.

```
<img lazy-load src="image.jpg" />
```

To make sure the image.jpg does not get fetched yet before javascript kicks in, we just add a placeholder to the src and add a attribute on the element which will be available in the directive.

```
<img lazy-load src="placeholder.jpg" origin-src="image.jpg" />
```

Now lets build the actual directive within the AngularJs Framework.

```
app.directive('lazyLoad', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function (scope, element, attrs) {

      var imagesrc = attrs.originSource;          
      // further logic to lazyload image
    }
  };

});
```

You can find many examples on Directives right here:
https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive

Answer (score 1):

Directive - I guess the terminology itself creates confusion to most of people. That's why angular people coming with 'Component' terminology with 2.0.

Directive is nothing but writing our own reusable custom tag and assigning some meaningfull functionality to it.

Lets say, we want to show an advertise panel over and over on all pages. It should depend on user history, preferences and also support lazy loading of images etc.

We can create a directive which will take image-name, preferece etc and will render it on its own.

We can create this as a reusable component and use it anywhere in the app by just including it in the html markup.

Answer (score 1):

Directives are defined classes that can add new behaviour or modify the existing behaviour to the DOM. The term "directives" Angular often refers to a combination of elements, attributes, and behaviours that work together to extend the functionality of HTML. It also contains the JavaScript functions (logic) that execute when these directives are applied.

There are basically following types in directives:

1. Attribute Directives: It includes *ngModel, *ngClass, *ngStyle.

   2. Structured Directives: It includes *ngFor, *ngIf *ngSwitch.
   3. Custom Directives: To create a custom directive we create a class with
      @Directive
      Let us take the samoke below example:
   4. Create a new angular project
   5. Generate a component for example let us create item-list component
   6. Define a list of component

import { Component } from '@angular/core';

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-item-list',
  templateUrl: './item-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./item-list.component.css']
})
export class ItemListComponent {
  items = ['Item 1', 'Item 2', 'Item 3'];
  showList = true;
}
```

4.Using directives in the template

```
 <div *ngIf="showList">
      <h2>List of Items</h2>
      <ul>
        <li *ngFor="let item of items">{{ item }}</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div *ngIf="!showList">
      <p>The list is hidden.</p>
    </div>
    <button (click)="showList = !showList">
      Hide the list
    </button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Directives are the central coding idea in Angular and the source of most of its power. They are an implementation of "Domain Specific Languages," which means that you, the programmer, get to make up your own language.

Although other comments here have focused on the HTML or the Javascript which **defines** the directive, neither of those is really the most important concept. The big takeaway is that writing a directive in your HTML results in **both** HTML and Javascript code (and likely Angular code, too) getting run. At the time a directive is defined, a **template** is indicated which tells which HTML will actually be output in place of the directive you wrote. But more importantly, a **controller** is also indicated which tells which code will be available for your HTML to access, including objects and functions.

```
ungallery.directive('footer', function() {
return {
    restrict: "E",
    controller: "footer",
    controllerAs: "footerController",
    templateUrl: 'directives/footer.html'
}
});
```

If this directive definition exists in my index.html (or any script loaded by it), then I can later write:

```
<footer></footer>
```

Into that index.html and have access to two things: the template that lives at "directives/footer.html" and a **controller** named "footer". Here's the definition of *footerController*. It exists only to give the HTML page visibility to the version number of the app, which I want to display in the footer of all pages:

```
var footerController = function() {
   this.version = CONSTANT.version;
};

ungallery.controller("footer", footerController);
```

The controller can assign any objects or functions to the object called **this** and those objects and functions will be available to the template HTML because of this directive wiring. This controller assigns one value to `this`, `this.version`, so that I can get to that value from my template.

In the directive's definition, the **controllerAs** syntax sets the name that I use to access the controller's `this` from the template. The reason that **controllerAs** syntax and separate names are used instead of just writing `{{this.something}}` is to prevent confusion when a page has several directives, each with its own meaning for `this`. In  the definition of the `footer` controller, `this` is accessed with the prefix `footerController`. Here's what this looks like in the template HTML when I want to display the actual version number.

```
 <span>Version {{footerController.version}}.</span>
```

Hope that helps! Let me know if I need to expand upon or clarify any of this.

-- D